# Unable to go back to login page

Tags: laravel

I have a login page and a middleware. The middleware checks to see if the user that is trying to log in is enabled or not and if they are not
enabled then they get taken to a page that says that they not enabled.

The problem I'm having is that when I reach that page and try to go back I'm not able to go back to the login page, I keep being directed
back to the check-enable page.

Here is my middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->path() == "check-enable") return $next($request);

    if($request->user() != null)
    {
        if($request->user()->enabled == 0)
        {
            return redirect('/check-enable');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

My check-enable page

```
@extends('layouts.single')
@section('title', 'User Disabled')
@section('content')
    <div class="float-left">
        <a href="{{ route('disabled.user.goBack') }}">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i> Go Back
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                You are disabled.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

and my method in my controller

```
public function disabledUserGoBack()
{
    Cache::flush();

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your routes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've to write your authentication code. You can check there itself whether user is enabled or not.

```
<?php
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'is_active' => 1]){
        return redirect('dashboard');
    }
    return redirect('login')->withErrors('Invalid credentials or user is not active yet').
?>
```

Please go through Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication/).